# .trigger() not working when manually trying to click div

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click

Want to use the trigger() method to manually click the menu on this link. Eventually would like to get a hover over the bar to manually bring out the nav.

http://matchboxlondon.com/ten/menu/index.html

Any help would be appreciated. .click() is a no-go, too.

Basically running this in the console does nothing:

```
$('#trigger').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Where is your code? Add your code here at SO.

Comment: Only adding 1 line of code would not help. We do not know where is your `#trigger` element in your HTML. Usage of `trigger()` is pretty straight forward and seems like you got it right, but we would need your HTML code or snippet to help.

Comment: `trigger('click')` will only execute attached click handler. It will not actuall click it. You may try `$('#trigger')[0].click()`

Comment: Nice one @Satpal. That's done it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use to trigger the DOM element click

```
$('#trigger').get(0).click();
```

Use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get), It retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. As `.click()` will trigger the element click event handler. **It will not actually click the element.**

Using simple Vanialla JS

```
document.getElementById('trigger').click()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4tnnu83/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code to trigger the event is correct. Check to make sure `#trigger` is the correct ID and that the element has a click event bound to it.

To bind it you could do something like:

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //do your own thing here
});
```